# Form not rendering updated label after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have been have problems with a postback from the button submit as after the button has finished the site think its a full refresh which gives me no chance to show any failure of login message or error,

I cant seem to pinpoint why this is happening and have looked up about the page cycle but can't put my finger on it.

Heres all my code for behind the page

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["user"]     = "";
        Session["domain"]   = "";
        Session["manager"]  = "";
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
            lblError.Text = "This was a post back.";
        else
            lblError.Text = "This was NOT a post back.";
    }
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Allows the variable to be used through out the app
        Session["user"]     = username;
        Session["domain"]   = domain;
        Session["manager"]  = null;

        if (true == authenticateUser(Session["domain"].ToString(), Session["user"].ToString(), password))
            Response.Redirect(Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("Update.aspx"));
    }
```

and front

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="Width:19%;" class="pure-form pure-   form-stacked">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="lblName"  runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginID" Width="95%" Style="display:inline-block;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
     </div>
    <br/>
    <asp:Label ID="lblpwd" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Width="95%" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lbldmn" runat="server" Text="Domain"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDomain" Width="95%" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>hdnl.it</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>yodel.net</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:Label>
    <br />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" Width="95%" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" 
                CssClass="button-success pure-button" />
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1"  runat="server" 
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"> 
        <ProgressTemplate> 
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="modal">
                <h2>Please Wait.....</h2>
                <img alt="Loading..." src="/Images/loading.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress> 
</form>
```

Comment: According to my understanding: when the submit button is clicked, if there is a login error, you want to show that in lblError.Text. is that right? If so, you need to move the label under the update panel

Comment: yeah that is correct I will try that now

Comment: That has worked thank you :)